# Printing array using printf with space between characters

Tags: c, arrays, printf

This one is simple, I have an array of chars and I want to print it but I want to have a space between each individiual member of array, is this possible with printf? Or do I have to prepare a separate function?

Example:

```
char array[]="hello";
printf ("%s", array);
```

Output:

```
h e l l o
```

Comment: You have to create a (simple) function to do the job.

Comment: You need a separate function, eg: `void spacedprint(const char *s) { putchar(*s++); while (*s) { putchar(' '); putchar(*s++); }}`

Comment: How many space do you expect to be printed with `""`, `"h"` and `"he"`?  (0,0,1)?

Comment: @pmg: you should test for a non-empty string before printing anything, but otherwise your code is what I had in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `void spacedprint(const char *s) { if (s && *s) { /* see older comment */ }}`

Comment: Well I already made the function, it prints each member of an array with a space right after it (and a little fix after the last char)

Comment: @Luk164: little fix is probably wrong. At the very least it has a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @Luk164 The question loosely uses the idea of array of chars and string interchangeably - and they are not quite the same.  With `char array[]="hello";`, `array` is an array 6 of `char`. so printing a space between each would print `h-sp-e-sp-l-sp-l-sp-o-sp-\0`.  OTOH, is code is to print a space between each character of a _string_, not including the `'\0'`, output could be `h-sp-e-sp-l-sp-l-sp-o`. As with weddings and programing, the details drive one crazy.  Please specify more cases including short arrays.

Comment: @chux: don't forget `char buff[1000] = "hello";` :-)

Comment: Yeah I was just curious if it is possible to do just using printf, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want an extra space after the final character:

```
char *tmp = array;
if (*tmp) {
    putchar(*tmp++);
    while (*tmp) {
        putchar(' ');
        putchar(*tmp++);
    }
}
```

Or turn it into a function:

```
void put_with_spaces(const char *s, FILE *fp)
{
    if (!*s)
        return;
    fputc(*s++, fp);
    while (*s) {
        fputc(' ', fp);
        fputc(*s++, fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice use of file pointers to store the contents!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach also to solve your task

```
 int main(){
    char array[]="hello";
    char *p=&array;
    while(*p) {
     printf("%c ",*p); 
       p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
h e l l o
```

Comment: Also you can simply use for and do printf("%c ", array[0]) You just have to do it one less time than lenght of array and then do one separate or you will end up with one more space than you need

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of array,let it be n then

`for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%c ",arr[i]);`

Notice a whitespace i.e `' '` is written after `%c`.This ensures a whitespace after every character from array is printed(whitespace will also be there after the last element).
And if you dont know the length of array then you can use while loop with condition that array with end with null just while printing each element provide a space after `%c`.

Comment: This will also cause there to be one more space character than required.

Answer (score 1):

A new solution occurred to me as I was browsing this question

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%*c", 1 + !!i, arr[i]);
}
```